# Magento 2: override Magento\Review\Block\Product\View not working

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to override the product view review block in Magento 2, but I can't get it to work.

**app/code/[Package]/CombineReviews/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Package]_CombineReviews" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/[Package]/CombineReviews/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View" type="[Package]\CombineReviews\Block\Magento\Review\Product\View" />
</config>
```

**app/code/[Package]/CombineReviews/Block/Magento/Review/Product/View.php**

```
<?php 
    
    namespace [Package]\CombineReviews\Block\Magento\Review\Product;

    class View extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View {
    /**
     * Review collection
     *
     * @var ReviewCollection
     */
    protected $_reviewsCollection;

    /**
     * Review resource model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_reviewsColFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $urlEncoder,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $string,
            $productHelper,
            $productTypeConfig,
            $localeFormat,
            $customerSession,
            $productRepository,
            $priceCurrency,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->getProduct()->setShortDescription(null);

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Replace review summary html with more detailed review summary
     * Reviews collection count will be jerked here
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param bool $templateType
     * @param bool $displayIfNoReviews
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function getReviewsSummaryHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $templateType = false,
        $displayIfNoReviews = false
    ) {
        return $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Review\Block\Rating\Entity\Detailed'
        )->setEntityId(
            $this->getProduct()->getId()
        )->toHtml() . $this->getLayout()->getBlock(
            'product_review_list.count'
        )->assign(
            'count',
            $this->getReviewsCollection()->getSize()
        )->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Get collection of reviews
     *
     * @return ReviewCollection
     */
    public function getReviewsCollection()
    {
        if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
            $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->addStatusFilter(
                \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
            )->addEntityFilter(
                'product',
                3
                //$this->getProduct()->getId()
            )->setDateOrder();
        }
        return $this->_reviewsCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Force product view page behave like without options
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasOptions()
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

In the function ReviewCollection I made a small modification:

```
)->addEntityFilter(
    'product',
    3
    //$this->getProduct()->getId()
```

This modification is working from the core files, but not in my custom module. I also tried to return 'test' from this function, but I can't get it to work.

Is there someone who sees the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify you `app/code/[Package]/CombineReviews/etc/module.xml` with following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Package]_CombineReviews" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Change the path of file from app/code/[Package]/CombineReviews/Block/Magento/Review/Product/View.php to app/code/[Package]/CombineReviews/Block/Product/View.php.

Run `setup: upgrade` and `static-content: deploy` commands and check. Hope this should work.